# Calling Managed Code From Unmanaged C

Tags: c, vb.net, dll, sql-server-2008-r2

So after about a day and a half with this I've made zero progress.

I need to write a DLL in C that is used a plugin for an existing application.
The DLL has to be compiled by the Visual Studio 2008 compiler with the following options

> cl -DNT40 -DPOMDLL -DCRTAPI1=_cdecl -DCRTAPI2=cdecl -D_WIN32 -DWIN32 -DWIN32_LEA
>   N_AND_MEAN -DWNT -DBYPASS_FLEX -D_INTEL=1 -DIPLIB=none -I. -I"C:\plm\2T-RAC\TcEx
>   press53\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include"
>    -c -nologo -EHsc -W1 -Ox -Oy- -MD C:\mydir\myDll.c

It's then linked to applications library's.

What it actually needs to do and what's causing me the issues is that within one of the methods it needs to pull data from a sql server 2008 r2.

From what I've seen today you wouldn't be able to do this directly in C as SQL Server past 2005 is designed to communicate with CLR languages( C#, C++, VB.Net).

It was suggested that I handle all the database communication with a VB.Net dll and then call said function from within the C dll.

Most of what I've found on the topic of calling managed dll's from unmanaged code has talked about pinvoke or com wrappers and mainly from the perspective of c++.

I have zero experience with COM or any mentioned techniques so if anyone could help out it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could create a [native C++ DLL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) then `extern "C"` functions you would like to expose to your C code.

Comment: What do you have to do in SQL? A query? SQL Server has **NOT** been made to communicate only with .NET languages!!! You can execute a query or run SQL commands from any language you can imagine (take a look to ADO, ODBC, OLEDB and so on).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting dll functions to unmanaged programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647766/exporting-dll-functions-to-unmanaged-programs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I resolved this was simply having the C dll call cmd and execute a compile VB.NET executable and pipe it's output.
Although this isn't wasn't a totally ideal solution it worked in this situation when all I required back was a single string.

Answer (score 10):

You have a lot of options to do this but not all of them are trivial.

### **Mixed mode assembly**

The first, and more easy way, to *export* managed code to a C client is to write your code using C++/CLI (or to write a wrapper using that language). You simply export the C functions you need as you would do in normal unmanaged code and inside their implementation you call the managed functions you need. Here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177552%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

### **COM Interop**

You export your managed classes as COM objects. From unmanaged code you'll see normal COM objects, take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2005/06/26/432870.aspx).

### **Reverse P/Invoke**

You can do it in different ways. The more simple one is to revert the point of view. If you have a VB.NET assembly (`vbnet.dll`) and a C library (`purec.dll`) the first thing you may imagine is to add a *dependency* to `vbnet.dll` in `purec.dll`. If you do it in this way you have to use COM or to make your application a .NET host. A more easy way is to revert: add a dependency to `purec.dll` in `vbnet.dll` (using P/Invoke). Your C interface will export a `struct` (for example) that can be filled with function pointers, you'll fill that `struct` in VB.NET (as delegates) and your C code will simply call them. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx).

### **Other options**

**Native host**: this is the hard way. Your native application will host the .NET application. It's long and complicated, I guess it's too much if you only need to export few functions. I post here just for reference: [hosting overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx).
**IPC**. You can keep your application separated and each other can ignore how the other one is written. Simply define an interface and a channel to connect them (named pipes, shared memory or anything else, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a list). This works if your VB.NET application is a service or it's hosted by a running application, if it simply exports few functions you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an existing vb.net dll (business layer) that you use everywhere, I'd probably recommend against using it in a C application.

There are various ways to communicate with MSSQL from C.  Either by a native driver or ODBC, etc.