# Vb.net DLL method not visible

Tags: java, vb.net, dll, jna, dependency-walker

I have created a VB.net DLL with Visual Basic Express very simple, this is my code :

```
Public Class Class1
  Public Function SayHello() As String
    Return "Hello"
  End Function
End Class
```

- I Would like to use this DLL from JAVA with JNA, but Eclipse say me than the procedure "SayHello" doesn't exist in my DLL.
- When i use tools like "Dependency Walker", my function isn't visible.

**So my question : how can i make this function callable and visible ??**

Thanks.
Vincent.

Comment: JNA can only access C++ dll. You gonna have to build a c++ wrapper around your VBNet lib.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Managed Code From Unmanaged C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821109/calling-managed-code-from-unmanaged-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call .NET code from Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283679/how-can-i-call-net-code-from-java)

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the comments indicate:

JNA is only able to provide "Java bindings" (i.e. lets you call methods from Java) for methods in **native** PE32 / PE32+ dlls. VB.Net dlls are in contrast always **managed** dlls.

To distinguish between native and managed dlls you may use e.g. one of the tools `dumpbin` or `corflags`; the first shipping with e.g. Visual Studio, the second comes with e.g. recent Microsoft SDKs.

Calling `dumpbin /dependents` on a questioned *managed dll* will show a dependency from `mscoree.dll`.

Calling `corflags` on a questioned *native dll* will show an error (s.th. like `The specified file does not have a valid managed header`)

This info is taken from [Is this DLL managed or unmanaged?](http://tiku.io/questions/267785) but has been verified by me, too.